# How to clear Chilkat CkHttpRequest Path property?

Tags: c++, chilkat

In the Chilkat CkHttpRequest C++ class, how to clear the Path property? It is always set to '/', even if I set the Path property to an empty string! I must be able to do that, since if I am setting the HttpVerb property to "OPTIONS", then I want the path to be '*' and not "/*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.  Chilkat did not account for the one case where the Path might not start with a "/", and it's for the "OPTIONS *" case as you described.

I'll update Chilkat for the next version to allow "*".

You can get a pre-release build if you are a licensed customer with non-expired support/maintenance (by sending email to support@chilkatsoft.com)

Comment: Another issue is that when I set the HttpVerb property to "OPTIONS", and send the request via the method SynchronousRequest, the header "Content-Length" gets added implicitly. How do I force it such that the "Content-Length" header is not added? @chilkat-software

Comment: We updated Chilkat to suppress the "Content-Length: 0" header when the verb is "OPTIONS".  This change of behavior will be in the next official release (v9.5.0.97) due out at the end of January 2024.

Comment: Thank you. I confirm that both issues were resolved in the release v9.5.0.97.